# IE9 memory leak

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I'm noticing, in my app, the memory associated with the IE process on Win7 climbs by 20-30 MB with each page refresh.  Once I reach about 1.5 GB, the browser becomes unresponsive.  I'm using IE9, and can only reproduce this in IE9.  No such issue in Chrome, FF, IE7, or IE8.  In fact, the issue also does not occur when running IE9 in compatibility mode.

In particular, I'm wondering how memory could leak even after a page refresh.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: this is a pretty hard issue to adress. I guess it could be for many reasons, sorry :-(

Comment: There is no way to provide code snippets for an large scale application.  If I could provide snippets, I would already have my answer as this would require me to narrow down the problem to a specific area of the code.  As my question states, I'm looking for others who have run into the same situation as myself: memory leak even after page reload (IE9 only), as well as some explanation as to how this could happen, in a general sense.

Comment: Check out my new answer Ray, just figured out this problem today (had the same issue with the newest release of a product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, Internet Explorer had some problems with references between usual JavaScript variables and DOM objects. So, if I remember correctly, a circular reference like this

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
var x = { elementReference: e };
e.jsReference = x;
```

would not be garbage-collected, even if there were no other references to `e` and `x`. This is because IE used different methods of garbage collection for DOM elements and JavaScript.

Now, I believed this problem was already remedied in IEs of higher versions, but maybe it wasn't. Try to find all such problematic references and manually remove them if you don't need them anymore.

```
e.jsReference = null;
x.elementReference = null;
```

**Edit: Test in IE 8**

I wrote this simple test webpage.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leak test</title>
    <script>
      function leak() {
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        var x = { elementReference: e };
        e.jsReference = x;
      }

      function test() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
          leak();
        alert('Done');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I tested this in IE 8, as I don't have IE 9 installed on this machine. However, this still may be relevant as it shows that the issue was still present even in quite recent versions of IE and thus it may persist even in IE 9.

I opened the page and watched the memory usage. After each pressing of the button, memory usage increased by several MB. After refreshing the webpage, absolutely nothing happened. After closing IE, the memory usage returned to its original state.

You may try that for yourself in IE 9. Of course, you probably aren't allocating 10000 circularily referring objects in your code, but you probably create larger objects that may contain some circular reference you haven't found yet.

Comment: Would this explain rapidly growing memory with each page reload?  I was under the impression that the issue of circular refs between host objects and native objects would not explain increasing memory with each page reload.  Also, I am not explicitly creating any circular refs.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this would be your issue, but I was also getting this IE9 memory leak issue where the memory kept growing and growing (about 20mgs per refresh / page change).

If you are using Modernizr (this should be fixed now in one of the very recent releases, 2.5+ I believe), but if you are using an older version (and can't just update it for any reason) then all you need to do is replace one `return` statement.

The problem is occurring with **Modernizr / Geolocation & IE9**, it is actually an inherit issue with IE9, not so much Modernizr.

```
return 'geolocation' in navigator
```

instead of:

```
return !!navigator.geolocation // this causes the memory leak (silly IE9)
```

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/513

Take a look at that link, but basically the return statement for the Geolocation test needs to be changed, and this problem will fix itself!

Comment: That was my problem and your suggestion saved me. Well-deserved upvote!

Comment: @danradu anytime :) Yeah this drove me nuts for a little while too... glad it helped someone else!

Comment: Wow... such a simple solution to a problem that's been bothering us for a while.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanRupp Glad to help, yeah this drove me insane for weeks too... haha